# Run python module from command line

Tags: python, bash

I don't really know how to ask this question but I can describe what I want to achieve. I would update any edits that would be suggested.

I have a python module that makes use of some command line arguments. Using the module requires some initial setup **outside** of the python interpreter. The python file that does the setup runs fine, but the problem is that I have to dig through the python installation to find where that file is located i.e. I have to do `python full-path-to-setup-script.py -a argA -b argB` etc.I would like to call the setup script like this

`some-setup-command -a argA -b argB` etc.

I want to achieve something like

`workon environmnent_name` as in the virtualenv module or

`pipenv install` as in the `pipenv` module.

I know both of the above commands call a script of some kind (whether bash or python). I've tried digging through the source codes of `virtualenv` and `pipenv` without any success.

I would really appreciate if someone could point me to any necessary resource for coding such programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to understand what you're looking for, but `python -m` is my best guess.

For example, to make a new Jupyter kernel, we call

```
python -m ipykernel arg --option --option
```

Where `arg` is the CLI argument and `option` is a CLI option, and `ipykernel` is the module receiving the `arg`s and `option`s.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll accept your answer as this is what I finally went for. Though @James answer also worked but taking that route required me to do more work. In case anyone is interested I wanted this for exactly this https://github.com/chidimo/python-git#setup

Comment: In addition, I had to create a `__main__.py` as contained in this post https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/. I looked up the source folder for `pipenv` and there was a `__main__.py` and a `__version__.py`. Real eye-openers

Answer (score 4):

If `full-path-to-setup-script.py` is executable and has a proper shebang line

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

then you can

```
ln -s full-path-to-setup-script.py ~/bin/some-command
```

considering `~/bin` exists and is in your `PATH`,
and you'll be able to invoke

```
some-command -a argA -b argB
```

Answer (score 2):

Commands that are callable from the command prompt are located in one of the directories in your system's `PATH` variable.  If you are on Windows, you see the locations via:

```
echo %PATH%
```

Or if you want a nicer readout:

```
powershell -c "$env:path -split(';')"
```

One solution is to create a folder, add it to your system's `PATH`, and then create a callable file that you can run.  In this example we will create a folder in your user profile, add it to the path, then create a callable file in that folder.

```
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\path
set PATH=%PATH%%USERPROFILE%\path;
setx PATH %PATH%
```

In the folder `%USERPROFILE%\path`, we create a batch file with following content:

```
# file name:
# some-command.bat
#
python C:\full\path\to\setup-script.py %*
```

Now you should be able to call

```
some-command -a argA -b argB
```

And the batch file will call python with python script and pass the arguments you added.

Comment: Just saw you had `bash` as one of the tags.  Adding info for linux

Comment: Thanks for this. Because of this I actually pulled up `workon.bat` file from `virtualenv` and took a look. It was a real eyeopener. Could you suggest any good tutorial on writing `.bat` scripts? I'd really appreciate. And btw would this have worked cross-platform?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the above answers, I see no one has mentioned this:

You can of course compile the python file and give executable permissions with

```
chmod +x filename.py
```

and then run it as

```
./filename.py -a argA -b argB ...
```

Moreover, you can also remove the extention `.py` (since it is an executable now) and then run it only as

```
./filename -a argA -b argB ...
```